# Pandas groupby into unique sets and then value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Was just wondering if there was a better way to do this. Basically I have some categories I want to find all unique combos for each val, and then count the number of instances for each category. The inclusion of the `astype(str)` irks me.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'cat': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'],
        'val': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
    }
)

df.groupby('val')['cat'].apply(lambda x: set(x)).astype(str).value_counts()
```

**Out:**

```
{'a', 'b'}    2
{'c', 'a'}    1
{'b'}         1
{'c'}         1
Name: cat, dtype: int64
```

The following does not give the desired result

```
df.groupby('val')['cat'].unique().value_counts()
```

**Out:**

```
[b]       1
[c, a]    1
[a, b]    1
[c]       1
[a, b]    1
```

Comment: So.. What is the issue in the code?

Comment: There's no issue with the groupby apply, it just seems hacky to me that I need to convert the set series into a str series and was wondering if there was a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) into [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) or [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) since they are hashable, then use `Series.value_counts`

```
df.groupby('val').agg(tuple).value_counts()
#               _.agg(frozenset).value_counts() works fine too.

cat   
(a, b)    2
(a, c)    1
(b)       1
(c)       1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: hmm i think only frozenset works, see `df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 'val': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]})`

Comment: @bbd108 If you consider `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` as similar go with frozenset, else use `tuple`it maintains the order of insertion. And `frozenset` removes duplicates too.

Comment: Accepting for frozenset, thanks for pointing out its hashable